# Flagging as SPAM too harsh?

Tags: discussion, support

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486910/90054) looked like a spammer testing the grounds to me, so I flagged it as SPAM.

*However,* one second after pushing that flag, I was wondering if I should have used one of the other flags as this doesn't help SmokeDetector at all.

Did I do:

- the right thing?
- the wrong thing?

Comment: Or am I being too cautious and it doesn't really matter?

Comment: Smokey isn't relevant here, it has no access to flags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best flag to use for nonsense post is actually either "not an answer" or "rude or abusive". The rationale for which is nicely explained by Shog in [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/203101):

> This is an utter waste of time. There is no meaning to the post! It's
>   VLQ, it's abuse, it's Not An Answer, heck it might even be a spammer,
>   testing the waters... There's no metric you can apply that'll narrow
>   that down, because there is no meaningful content to apply metrics to.
>
> So pick the flag that speaks to you. I'm partial to "rude or abusive",
>   because enough of them immediately delete and lock the post, which is
>   handy in those rare scenarios where someone's flooding the site with a
>   lot of these... But VLQ or NAA work just as well in the vast majority
>   of cases. The important thing to remember here is that when the post
>   clearly means nothing, you shouldn't be wasting too much thought
>   trying to decipher it; flag it and move on with your life.

That said, the only difference between spam and R/A (rude or abusive) flags is that R/A flagged posts are never used in review audits. Apart from that, I understand that the system treats both in the same way. However, I personally prefer to limit spam flags for actual *spam*, cases where someone is trying to promote something, since that tells me as a moderator handling the flag what to look for. So yes, I would prefer you flag that as R/A instead of spam if only to help me get into the right frame of mind to evaluate the flag. But it really doesn't make that much of a difference, no.

By the way, I've written up [a guide](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15921/85695) for which flag to use where on Ask Ubuntu's meta, and the directions there are also valid for here.